# Usar while en python

Tags: python, while

Resulta que soy nuevo en esto y no sé muy bien el como usar el ciclo **while**. Quiero hacer un programa de una calculadora sencilla, sin embargo me gustaría que al elegir las opciones de sumar, restar, multiplicar o dividir si la persona elige una letra o caracter que no este disponible se le volviese a repeir la misma pregunta hasta que la respuesta sea válida. Si ven algún fallo o algo que se pueda mejorar, me gustaría que me lo dijeran también. Gracias.

Aquí el código:

```
print("Bienvenido")

Name = (input("Cómo te llamas? "))

Respuesta = print(""" 


    Bienvenido. Esta es una calculadora que realiza divisiones,multiplicaciones, restas, y divisiones.
    A continuacion habra una lista con las posibles operaciones que puedes realizar.
    Solo presiona las teclas disponibles para cada operación.

    """)


suma = print("a = sumar")
resta = print("b = restar")
division = print("c = dividir")
multiplicacion = print("d = multiplicar")

Valor_2 = input("{0} elija una opción: ".format(Name))
if (Valor_2 == 'a'):
    print("")
elif (Valor_2 == 'b'):
    print("")
elif (Valor_2 == 'c'):
    print("")
elif (Valor_2 == 'd'):
    print("")

Valor_1 = int(input("Ingrese el número: "))
Valor_3 = int(input("Ingrese el número: "))

if (Valor_2 == 'a'):
    print("OK...")
elif (Valor_2 == 'b'):
    print("OK...")
elif (Valor_2 == 'c'):
    print("OK...")
elif (Valor_2 == 'd'):
    print("OK...")

if (Valor_2 == 'a'):
    print("El resultado es:",Valor_1 + Valor_3)
elif (Valor_2 == 'b'):
    print("El resultado es:",Valor_1 - Valor_3)
elif (Valor_2 == 'c'):
    print("El resultado es:",Valor_1 / Valor_3)
elif (Valor_2 == 'd'):
    print("El resultado es:",Valor_1 * Valor_3)
else:
    print ('Elige una opción correcta')
```

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar digamos que `input("Ingrese el número: ")` retorna una cadena, la misma puede ser **(a)** un valor que pueda convertirse en un entero con la función `int()` o **(b)** cualquier otra cadena que no pueda tratarse como un número entero. La idea, entonces, podría ser: ***pedir una entrada por teclado mientras el valor ingresado no pueda convertirse a un entero***.

Lo primero que deberíamos armar, es la lógica para saber si una cadena puede convertirse a un entero, y la forma más simple, es intentar convertirla y ver si nos da un error (Excepción) o no. Por ejemplo algo así:

```
def convert_to_num(cadena):
  try:
    return int(cadena)
  except ValueError:
    return None
```

Esta función retornará un entero, producto de la conversión de `cadena` a un `int` o un `None` en caso de error. Luego, y ahora sí, usaremos el `while` para seguir solicitándole al usuario, el ingreso de un valor mientras éste no sea un entero o más bien, mientras `convert_to_num()` nos retorne `None`:

```
def input_valid_number(msg):

  num = convert_to_num(input(msg))
  while not num:
    print("!!! Error. Lo ingresado no es un número entero")
    num = convert_to_num(input(msg))

  return num
```

Para usar lo anterior, simplemente hacemos:

```
num1 = input_valid_number("Ingrese el número 1: ")
num2 = input_valid_number("Ingrese el número 2: ")

print("Los números ingresados son: {0} y {1}".format(num1, num2))
```

Nota: En `while not num` usamos una propiedad de `None` que a nivel lógico se considera `False` por lo que `Not False = True` y logramos que el ciclo se repita mientas la cadena no pueda ser transformada en un número.